# How many times throughout the Dune novels is Duncan Idaho ghola'd?

Tags: novel, dune

Throughout the Dune novels I would like to know how many times Duncan Idaho is ghola'd (cloned) before he reaches Kwisatz Haderach status?

Comment: Care to add some context as to why you find this interesting?

Comment: This question is unanswerable: Duncan is brought back as a ghola numerous times throughout Leto II's 3,500 year reign and the number of times he's brought back is never specified.

Comment: If I remember correctly in the non-Frank Hebert Sandworms of Dune sequel a number is mentioned but this can also only be a rough estimate made by the new authors. Sorry I made an effort to forget ever reading the new books, that's why it's so in-accurate.

Comment: It could be just my imagination, but I think in one book one of the gholas specifically asks the god emperor how many gholas there were before, but he specifically denies the answer.

Answer (score 29):

According to the Dune wiki:

> At least one Duncan Idaho ghola
>   features in every novel from Dune
>   Messiah through Sandworms of Dune.

Because a few gholas survive from one novel to the next (from *Dune Messiah* to *Children of Dune*, from *Heretics of Dune* to *Chapterhouse: Dune*, and from *Hunters of Dune* to *Sandworms of Dune*), this means that four Duncan gholas are featured as characters in the novels. But the number of non-featured gholas is way higher than four.

I don't remember seeing a definitive count mentioned in any of the novels, but I have refrained from reading anything not written by Frank himself, so I can't vouch for that. Unless Brian and KJA provided a definitive number, I doubt you can do any better than guessing.

Since Leto II kept ordering gholas from the Bene Tleilax during his 3500-years reign, and, obviously, not every single one of these is mentioned, you cannot have a definite and accurate count. After Leto's reign, the Bene Gesserit kept using the Duncan gholas provided by the Tleilaxu for another fifteen hundred years, and again, an unknown number of them were provided. It's a total of five thousand years of Duncan gholas.

In *God Emperor of Dune*, it is mentioned that only nineteen of the gholas the God Emperor used died a natural death. Most of them rebelled and ended up killed by the God Emperor. This does not help much in getting an absolute total count, though.

If I had to provide an estimate, I would say anything between one hundred and fifty (a fairly optimistic average of about thirty years per ghola) to one thousand Duncan gholas (a more pessimistic average of five years per ghola). Not a very tight interval but that's what I can work from the data available to me.

Comment: Thanks for answering the "hidden" question about the gholas we *are* aware of.

Comment: @Mark Trapp: I guess I failed on that part: isn't the ghola in Messiah the same ghola featured in Children of Dune? Ooops! The one in Heretics is also the one in Chapterhouse, and the one in Hunters appears to be the one in Sandworms. :(

Comment: @Mark, @Martinho,  Much higher than that. When you read the books, its obvious it's in the hundreds, if not thousands. There is one para I remember reading, ghola turns up, new from the axoltl tank, and it reminds Leto II of the original Duncan, and he kills it instantly, seconds after it's arrived and mulls on many he's killed for that one reason.

Comment: @scope_creep right, but "a whole bunch" isn't a particularly satisfying answer to the question "how many?" Martinho's answer is a great way to turn an unanswerable but otherwise well-intentioned question into an answerable one.

Comment: @Mark, the whole point of the Ghola, outside the books in they are human and can be killed whereas Leto II can't be, so it provides a plot device to illustrate a dichotomy between a human and a god. It is not essential to know how many Gholas exists, the plot only requires that they do exist.

Comment: @scope_creep all that's great, but that's not what the question asked.

Comment: @Mark, its central to why the number of ghola isn't really defined.

Answer (score 9):

*The Dune Encyclopaedia* provides an interesting alternative perspective on this.

Out-of-universe (approximately, anyway), the actual *Encyclopaedia* itself has 21 **Idaho, Duncan** entries.  One of those is not a ghola, of course.  The second and third entries cover the same person.  So that's 19 gholas with *Encyclopaedia* entries.  (No, they are *not* the nineteen who died natural deaths.)

In-universe, according to the *Encyclopaedia* itself:

> The "Welbeck Fragment" indicates that prior to 13663 nine Duncans had suffered violent deaths and nineteen had died of natural causes.  These figures are now known to be highly inaccurate.  Leto II's diaries in the Dar-es-Balat hoard have already indicated that over twenty Duncan gholas failed to survive the first-contact interview with the Fish Speakers, and the initial survey of the diaries reveals that there were well over seventy Duncans delivered by the Bene Tleilax.

The same entry notes that the Duncan Idaho ghola of 13663 is the second longest lived on record, having lived for sixty years.  70 gholas over 3500 years is a mean lifespan of 50 years, of course.  More than 70, and the mean is lower.

In the *Encyclopaedia*'s universe, the in-universe answer is thus "We don't know, because we've discovered that there were a lot more than there were let on to be.".  Although the *Encyclopaedia* is officially divergent from the later novels, where there are of course yet more gholas after the *Encyclopaedia*'s Duncan-The-Last, it is a fair speculation that "a number that only the Bene Tleilax know" is the common in-universe answer.

Interesting tidbit:  In the *Encyclopaedia*'s universe, the Duncan Idaho ghola of 12301 is also a Kwisatz Haderach, who is killed by the Fish Speakers almost immediately.  But you probably weren't allowing for that in your question.  ☺

Comment: The mean number assumes that a new ghola is only created upon the death of a previous one and that it is instantly created at that moment in time.  It's more likely that either the Tleilax had "spares" sitting around or that they only started the process of creating one once an order came in.  Growing a ghola implies that it takes some amount of time to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In Heretics of Dune he received the memory from *all* his past lives and it said he had the memory of thousands of lives and thousands of deaths. He remembered being flattened by the God Emperor time and again. He was also acclaimed as being the father of a thousand children.

Answer (score 0):

According to Idaho, he was cloned '*hundreds*' of times. Note that by this point he has access to all of their shared memories.

> Why did Paul’s son have the Tleilaxu provide him with my ghola-self,
> hundreds of me! for all those thousands of years?
>
> <sub><sup>Heretics of Dune</sup></sub>

It is, of course, not clear whether he means two hundred or nine hundred, but we can at least place an upper and lower bound on it. Probably it's a few hundred.

Comment: Provided that Tleilaxu re-used cells from every ghola. What if those that failed manufacturer quality inspection right out of the tank weren't? or those, who died without their cells being harvested by Tleilaxu? Certainly happened - accident that nothing useful remains would be a possibility in Idaho's line of work. Also, question is not about gholas of consequence... I'd double whatever estimate you put here. ;-)

Comment: @AcePL - Idaho appears to also have memories from those that weren't harvested.

Comment: Well, no one knew they harvested the original and what else they put in the package of first one... So I'd add "...as far as we know" to your reply anove...